# Javascript: Change Text Value Between Two Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I have some buttons. Like this:

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
```

If I click `two` and `six`, the order changed like this:

```
one
six
three
four
five
two
```

Comment: can you show us what have you done so far?

Comment: @ShadowFiend Just create HTML. Every button, I name with class "button"

Comment: @Zen we can't help if you don't show us the code

Comment: @Zen post it here.. SO is not a free coding service you must write some code first and we will help you when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I did this :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var change ="a";
$("button").bind("click",function(){
if(change == "a"){
$(this).attr("id",change);
change =$(this).text();
}else{
$("#a").text($(this).text());
$(this).text(change);
change ="a";
$("#a").removeAttr("id");
} }) 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>one</button>
<button>two</button>
<button>three</button>
<button>four</button>
<button>five</button>
<button>six</button>
```